# What makes function composition so powerful?

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming

I have read about functional programming and it's core concept seem to be the high use of immutable datastructures, which in turn lead to pure functions. These pure functions ought be easily composable like in this example:

```
def add(x, y):
    return 3 + 3

def minus1(z):
    return z - 1

print(minus1(add(3,3)))
```

I understand, that i can compose functions and build new functions by this method. In the following example, i have composed two impure functions:

```
def add_list_last(arr):
    arr.append(1)
    return arr

def insert_entry_at_start(arr):
    arr.insert(0,1)
    return arr

print(add_list_last(insert_entry_at_start([1,2,3])))
```

Why can't i just compose impure functions like i did in the second example and why is it so powerful? What is the disadvantage of the second example and why is the mutation of the array preventing composability?

Comment: since lists are mutable in python you will be changing the original array. lets say you have an array called `original` and you run `modified = add_list_last(insert_entry_at_start(original))` you would expect original and modified to be different, but they are the exact same array(not a copy, but literally the same one)

Comment: There are lots of clever tricks you can do with functions provided that they are pure. However, if they are impure, that limits you a lot when `f(x)` is no longer the same operation every time. The simplest example is memoization - if `f` is no longer memoizable, then you lose an essentially free optimisation path for your code.

Comment: @VLAZ What do you mean by memoizable?

Comment: [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) is a way of caching. You essentially build up a map of inputs to outputs to a function. So, if you call `f(1)` and get `"a"`, you don't need to re-evaluate `f` a second time when `1` is passed into it, you just fetch it from the cache map. However, if `f(1)` can produce either `"a"` or `"b"`, then you cannot memoize the function - the same input doesn't necessarily produce the same output.

Answer (score 1):

```
T = TypeVar('T')

def split(v: T) -> Tuple[T, T]:
    return v, v

def apply_to_first(f: Callable[[T], T], *xs: T) -> Sequence[T]:
    return (f(xs[0]), *xs[1:])

apply_to_first(insert_entry_at_start, *split([1, 2]))
```

You would expect this result here:

```
([1, 2, 1], [1, 2])
```

But in fact you get:

```
([1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 1])
```

Because `insert_entry_at_start` is impure.

Comment: so the composition of pure functions is so powerful, because you are able compose new pure functions out of pure functions, correct?

Comment: Yes…!? Put differently, if any function in your functional program is impure and has side effects, it becomes hard to reason about how your program will behave.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified example:

```
def prepend_impure(lst, element):
    lst.insert(0, element)
    return lst

def prepend_pure(lst, element):
    cpy = lst[:]
    cpy.insert(0, element)
    return cpy

def combine(list1, list2):
    return [i + j for i, j in zip(list1, list2)]

list1 = [2, 3, 4]
list2 = [2, 3, 4]

print(combine(prepend_impure(list1, 1), prepend_impure(list1, 1)))
print(combine(prepend_pure(list2, 1), prepend_pure(list2, 1)))
```

Output:

```
[2, 2, 4, 6, 8]
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

The `prepend` functions insert an element at the beginning of a given `list` and return the `list`.

The `combine` function adds 2 lists together.

Personally, I would expect the code to both return `list`s of `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and add the 2 together.

Not only do you not get what you expect with the impure version.. In a large codebase, trying to be mindful of all the ways a function can mutate or modify your objects can produce a lot of cognitive overload.